# How do I remove this listener in OnDestroy (Android Firebase)?

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

This is my ValueEventListener in OnCreate method. I want to destroy this is OnDestroy method because it might be causing memory leak and also I've read it that it's a good practice to do so.

```
mDatabase.child(mPost_key).addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
            display_author = (String) dataSnapshot.child("author").getValue();
            display_quote = (String) dataSnapshot.child("quote").getValue();
            display_pic_url = (String) dataSnapshot.child("pic_url").getValue();
            categoryData=(String) dataSnapshot.child("catg").getValue();
            display_prof=(String) dataSnapshot.child("prof").getValue();
            copyQuote = (display_quote + " - " +display_author);
            try {
                author.setText(display_author);
                quote.setText(display_quote);
                category.setText(categoryData);
                profession.setText(display_prof);
                Glide.with(SingleExploreQuotes.this).load(display_pic_url).override(192, 192).into(profile_img);

            } catch (Exception e) {
                finish();
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 15, accepted):

When you register the listener, you get back a handle to the listener. Keep that listener in a member field:

```
private ValueListener mListener;

mListener = mDatabase.child(mPost_key).addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
```

And then remove the listener in your `onDestroy()`:

```
mDatabase.child(mPost_key).removeListener(mListener);
```

Answer (score 3):

With reference of @Frank van Puffelen's answer. Change code to:

```
private ValueEventListener mListener;
mListener = mDatabaseRef.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() 
{...}
```

in onDestry() :

```
@Override
    protected void onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy();
        mDatabaseRef.removeEventListener(mListener);
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

To copy Firestore's `ListenerRegistration` behavior and have the same seamless implementation, I implemented a custom class named `ListenerRegistration` as well, that accepts a `DatabaseReference` and a listener object, that is either a `ChildEventListener` or `ValueEventListener`.

```
import com.google.firebase.database.ChildEventListener;
import com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseReference;
import com.google.firebase.database.ValueEventListener;

import org.jetbrains.annotations.NotNull;

public class ListenerRegistration {

    private DatabaseReference mDatabaseReference;
    private Object mListener;

    ListenerRegistration(@NotNull DatabaseReference databaseReference,
                         @NotNull Object listener) {
        if (listener instanceof ChildEventListener || listener instanceof ValueEventListener) {
            mDatabaseReference = databaseReference;
            mListener = listener;
        } else {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("Listener type invalid");
        }
    }

    public void remove() {
        if (mListener instanceof ChildEventListener) {
            mDatabaseReference.removeEventListener((ChildEventListener) mListener);
        } else if (mListener instanceof ValueEventListener) {
            mDatabaseReference.removeEventListener((ValueEventListener) mListener);
        } else {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("Listener type invalid");
        }
    }

}
```

This way, every time I attach a listener, I just keep the value and then call `.remove()` as needed. e.g.

```
ValueEventListener listener = {...}
DatabaseReference dbRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference(NODE_ROOT).child(NODE_SAMPLE);
ListenerRegistration lr = new ListenerRegistration(dbRef, listener);
```

then somewhere like `onDestroy()`:

```
lr.remove()
```

Answer (score 0):

you can Remove any listener using removeEventListener method .you faced memory leak issues so clear memory of your Glide library in ondestroy  like this

```
@Override 
public void onDestroy() {
super.onDestroy();
//removelistener
mDatabase.child(mPost_key).removeEventListener(ValueEventListener);
Glide.get(this).clearMemory();//clear memory

}
```

Comment: it gives me error over ValueEventListener, telling me "Expression Expected".

Answer (score 0):

Just put below code in onDestroy()

```
@Override
protected void onDestroy() {
    super.onDestroy();
    if(!isFinishing()){
    mDatabase.child(mPost_key)..addValueEventListener(null);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

For those looking for the Firebase **Firestore** version of this answer Use ListenerRegistration and then call .remove() on it in onDestroy()

```
private ListenerRegistration listenerRegistration;

listenerRegistration = Reference.addsnapshotListener(new 
EventListener<QuerySnapshot>){
  @Override
        public void onEvent(QuerySnapshot documentSnapshots, 
        FirebaseFirestoreException e) {
         //get your data

  }
});


@Override
protected void onDestroy() {
    super.onDestroy();

    if(listenerRegistration != null) {
        listenerRegistration.remove();
    }

}
```