# Why pushing data to another node updates my RecyclerView filled with data from another node?

Tags: android, firebase

I have such JSON data(below only 2 nodes shown,but actually there are a lot)

```
  {
  "Node1" : {
    "-Kr20AYmoO5L2lbpMbka" : {
      "cityName" : "New York",
      "date" : "09-Aug-17"
    },
    "-Kr20_FZM_FBR7Ua2VoN" : {
      "cityName" : "Moscow",
      "date" : "09-Aug-17"
    },
    "-Kr22-yGRjXpW2aFq-u9" : {
      "cityName" : "Astana",
      "date" : "09-Aug-17"
    }
  },

   "Node2" : {
    "-Kr0GH7Wr-fN2ndCZgpS" : {
      "cityName" : "Washington",
      "date" : "08-Aug-17",
      "typeOfIcon" : 1
    },
    "-Kr0UxxpvxgXxu2wCqyL" : {
      "cityName" : "Chicago",
      "date" : "08-Aug-17",
      "typeOfIcon" : 1
    }

  }
}
```

What I want to do? Get data from node and show it on `RecyclerView`. If something happened, I have to show data of next node(in this case it is `Node2`) and push some data to previous node(in this case it is `Node1`).

What is the problem? I can easily show data from each node. But the problem is when I get data from some node and push data to `previous` node,my `RecyclerView` updates itself `also` with data from `previous` node(but without pushed data lastly) . Why can it happen? Below is my code:

```
@Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState); 
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_just);


        //all initializations are above 
        loadDataFromFirebase();
    }

    private void loadDataFromFirebase() {
            //below is array used to fill recyclerView
            cities = new ArrayList<>(); 
            final Firebase firebase = new 
             Firebase(FirebaseConfig.URL);
           //words array is {"Node1","Node2",.......};
           firebase.child(words.get(index))//index = 0 for the first time
                    .addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
                        @Override

                        public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {

                            for (DataSnapshot d : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {

                                City city = d.getValue(City.class);

                                cities.add(city);



                            }


citiesRecyclerView.setAdapter(new CityAdapter(MainActivity.this,cities));//show recyclerView

                        }

                        @Override
                        public void onCancelled(FirebaseError firebaseError) {

                        }
                    });
        }


        public void ifSomethingHappened() 
        {
          /*
          I call this method when it is needed 
          */
          index++; //incerement index in order to go to next node 
          loadDataFromFirebase(); //load data again from another node 
          pushCity();
        } 

private void pushCity() {

    int prevChildNodeIndex = index - 1 ; // get index of previous child(in this case it is Node1) 

    String prevChildNode = words.get(prevChildNodeIndex);  // Node1

    Firebase firebase = new Firebase(FirebaseConfig.URL);

    City city = getUsersCity(); // it is method that returns city,it is ok 

    firebase.child(prevChildNode).push().setValue(city); //push to previous node



}
```

As  I said before, I can successfully show data from any node. But when I go to next node and show data from this node,it is showed but with all data from previous node,because `push()` called after that. How can I solve that problem? I do not want to show data from previous node and I want to only show data of current node and only push to previous node. But as I've understood `push()` updates automatically `recyclerView` with data that was used to push data into.Hope that you have understood my problem. And how to solve that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't destroy old listener `ValueEventListener`. In node2 you got actually 2 `ValueEventListener`s. Change on node1 calls `onDataChange` and this probably adds to cities. Also it is better to clear cities ArrayList than creating new one

Comment: Thanks,but problem was solved by changing `addValueEvenListener` to `singleValueEventListener`

Comment: @andy11 yes, this works too as `singleValueEventListener` "destroys itself" after getting data. The only problem is that you will not get "realtime" data, but if it is okay for you then no problem

Comment: How to get only newest "realtime" data? I need to use approach that you wrote in answer? But I didn't understand that

Comment: You get data only once, that's why it is "singleValueEventListener". You don't listen to new "events" that happen after you got needed info in singleValueEventListener.

To keep data updated you have to use "active" listener (that listens all the time). Your first solution didn't remove old listener from node1. 

Try this to remove old listener and I think everything will be fine: 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41074095/how-do-i-remove-this-listener-in-ondestroy-android-firebase