# Android Firebase Database setvalue remove listener

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, setvalue

In my application Im running a foreground service which does upload stuff to Firebase Database with offline persistence enabled. I'm using the DatabaseReference `setvalue()` method and attaching a completion listener because I absolutely need to know if the data arrives at the server (due to the offline logout dataloss bug/feature in Firebase Database).

When my users log out of Firebase, I'm calling stopservice and I would like to detach any listeners within the ondestroy method. Because if I don't, I'm getting a memory leak since the oncompletionlistener holds on forever.

Now is there any way to remove this listener somehow? I find it pretty strange that there does not seem to be a legit way to remove the listener. I'm aware of the option to pass an Activity to the Tasks listeners but since I'm operating in a service thats not an option is it?

Every help is much appreciated. Thank you!

Please be aware that the setvalue method does not accept the new ValueEventListener() which of course is removable. Instead it uses the DatabaseReference.CompletionListener

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41074095/how-do-i-remove-this-listener-in-ondestroy-android-firebase

Comment: I have looked at this and there doesn't appear to be anything appropriate for setValue(). You are stuck with the listener you pass into the setValue method or stuck with a Task if you omit the listener parameter; neither of which appear to have an appropriate method to be detatched.

Comment: @ADM Thx but there is no removeListener() method for Completion Listeners

Comment: @Tom Bailey Thx for checking out. Yes that is what I was afraid of ... But I just couldn't believe that since its google!

Comment: Guys, before you mark as possible duplicate please first check the firebase reference. @ Alex Mamo Im not using new ValueEventListener. I know I can remove that. Please read that : https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/android/com/google/firebase/database/DatabaseReference